# Install grub from live CD

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have installed my Ubuntu onto a partition on the same drive where my windows is. I would like to install GRUB, but cannot access the Ubuntu installation as Windows starts instead. I am in the USB Live Version trying to install grub but I get this:

> grub-install dev\sda4
>
> cannot create directory /boot/grub/i386-pc permission denied

Please help me install GRUB.

Comment: ?Easiest method is to use boot-repair. You need to install grub to the MBR of the fist hard drive, not sda4. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` ...

Comment: why? I have the ubuntu installed on sda4

Comment: Read this question instead http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 1):

NO NEED TO RE INSTALL!

You can use what is called a chroot to access your installed partition from a live CD. See [How to chroot Ubuntu using Live CD to fix GRUB rescue prompt](https://web.archive.org/web/20190630193946/http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/02/how-to-chroot-to-ubuntu-using-live-cd-to-fix-grub-rescue-prompt/).

Basically how it works is you boot of the live CD and mount your Ubuntu install.  You run `chroot`, and you are dropped into a command prompt for the installed Ubuntu instance instead of the CD. The guide above should tells you what you need to do.

Comment: boot-repair is an easier method, see the link I gave. It is a graphical solution so easy to use and if it fails generates a url more experienced users can review to assist debugging.

Answer (score -2):

I thought that grub was installing automatically... Try re-installing. At the Ubuntu Set up choosing thing (where you can select dual-boot or replace windows) select the option with the gear. Now select the Ubuntu partition, remove it and re-create it. Re-install Ubuntu and grub will install automatically (I think, it did so with my installation).

The option with the gear is the bottom one (in ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: I would not advise re-installing Ubuntu to fix grub.